# SVG icons - badly vertical align

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using SVG icons in the button and they are badly vertical align. When I set up `vertical-align: middle` for them, the result is the same as when I set up `"bottom"` and so the icons are down too much.

When I change the setting to `vertical-align: top`, the icons are at `1px` higher. What is the universal way how to align them?

Of course, I could use for example: `vertical-align: top; margin-top: 1px;` but I don't want to have all icons in the button positioned by margin.

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/7nhcruw2/2/

Comment: You should add your markup to the question and not try to avoid the rules by posting a link that isn't really a link.

Comment: What exactly do you want ? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Robert: thanks, i forgot it. i Am newbie on STO

Comment: Sooraj: I want to have vertical align icon with text

Answer (score 1):

Try these changes:

```
.btn .ico {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.btn svg {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    fill: #fff;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/elrumordelaluz/eLf6my9z/1/) is the fiddle.

Comment: It doesn't work. I want to have vertical align icon with text. But in your fiddle is icon below, than text.